# equivariant cohomology of noncompact G-manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Assume that $G$ is a compact Lie group, and $M$ is a smooth $G-$manifold. We consider the equivariant cohomology of $M$, i.e. $H^{*}_{G}(M)$. The famous theorem of Cartan said that if $M$ is compact then the twisted de Rham complex $\Omega^{*}_{G}(M)$ computes the equivariant cohomology of $M$, i.e.
$$H^{*}_{G}(M)\simeq H^{*}(\Omega^{*}_{G}(M),d_{eq}).$$
So if $M$ is not compact is the above result aslo true ?

Comment: I think that it is still true. See §2.5 in "Supersymmetry... " by Guillemin-Sternberg.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the result  is true without the compactness assumption.  For a proof that describes *explicitly* this isomorphism, and does not rely on spectral sequences, [see this old note](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/cartan.pdf).